# Complemented subalgebra in a free Lie ring

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, abelian-groups, noncommutative-rings

A Lie ring is a triple $(G,+, [\ ,\ ]),$ where $(G,+)$ is an abelian group and $ [\ ,\ ]$ is  a bilinear map  satisfying

- $[x,x]=0$
- $[\ ,\ ]$ is bilinear
- $[[x,y],z]+[[y,z],x]+[[z.x],y]=0,\ \forall\ x,y,z\in G.$ (Jacobi identity).

The center of the Lie ring is defined as $$Z(G)=\{x\ |\ [x,y]=0,\ \forall\ y\in G\}.$$

Let $(G,+, [\ ,\ ])$ be a Lie ring with free presentation
$$0\rightarrow R\rightarrow F\rightarrow G\rightarrow 1.$$
Now consider the quotient Lie ring $\tilde{F}=\frac{F}{R\cap [F,F]}$ and $\tilde{R}=\frac{R}{R\cap [F,F]}$. Then the subring $Z(\tilde{F})\cap [\tilde{F},\tilde{F}]$ of $Z(\tilde{F})$ has a complement subring in  $Z(\tilde{F})$, i.e. there exists an ideal $\tilde{T}$ of $Z(\tilde{F})$ such that $$Z(\tilde{F})=Z(\tilde{F})\cap [\tilde{F},\tilde{F}]\times \tilde{T}.$$

My question is: $\textbf{How such an ideal $\tilde{T}$ exists?}$

> I have seen in the article [Isoclinism in pair of Lie rings](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/10.1142/S0219498820500310) that authors have taken as assumption that if $\tilde{x}=x+[R,F]\in\frac{F}{[R,F]} $ such that $\tilde{x}^n\in \frac{[F,F]}{[R,F]}$  for some integer $n\in \mathbb{N}$ then $\tilde{x}\in \frac{[F,F]}{[R,F]}$ and assumed that this holds. Using this assumption they claimed following two points:

$(1)$ The factor Lie ring $\frac{Z(\tilde{F})}{Z(\tilde{F})\cap [\tilde{F},\tilde{F}]}$ is isomorphic to some ideal of the free abelian Lie ring $\frac{\tilde{F}}{[\tilde{F},\tilde{F}]}$

$(2)$ There exists an ideal $\tilde{T}$ of $\tilde{F}$ such that $$Z(\tilde{F})=Z(\tilde{F})\cap [\tilde{F},\tilde{F}]\times \tilde{T}.$$

It can be seen that the second claim can be obtained from the first one, but I am not able to see the first one. Please guide me in this regard.

Comment: What do you mean by $\tilde{x}^n$? I don't what the $n$-power could mean in a Lie ring.

Comment: @YCor $\tilde{x}^n==\tilde{x}+\tilde{x}+\ldots +\tilde{x}$ ($n$-times) for the reference (Theorem 3.2 of \tilde{x}.)

Comment: Thanks, so it means $n\tilde{x}$, to be consistent with the additive notation.

Comment: How can this be helpful to deduce the result?

Comment: This is helpful to understand the question at least. I'll think about it now.

Comment: I think that the whole point is that $F/[F,F]$ is a torsion-free group. It is more practical to work inside $F$ itself. If $x\in F$, the condition $nx\in [F,F]+[F,R]$ just means $nx\in [F,F]$. And $[F,F]+[F,R]=[F,F]$. Since $F/[F,F]$ is torsion-free, this implies $x\in [F,F]$.

Comment: @YCor, Yes I understand this that how $F/[F,F]$ is torsion free. But now how can I conclude the rest of things?

Comment: How to conclude? I gave the argument in the last 3 lines of my previous comment. (I didn't justify why $F/[F,F]$ is torsion-free, but the latter point is clear: this is the "free abelian Lie algebra" on the given generating subset and is thus just the free abelian group on the basis.)

Comment: @YCor I am sorry, but my question is about the existence of complement subring in $Z(\tilde{F})$? How this can be concluded?

Comment: Could you clarify in your post what exactly the question is.

Comment: @YCor I have edited the question sir, please have a look on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139513/discussion-between-mani-and-ycor).

Comment: Since you're inside an abelian Lie algebra, you just mean a linear complement (i.e., as $\mathbf{Z}$-module). Now just use that a submodule of a free $\mathbf{Z}$-module is free. So you can lift the quotient.